# how to validate a user with username and password security?

Tags: wcf, authentication

I would like to use the username and password validation in a WCF project. So if I am not wrong, I have to implement the username passowrd validator interface. This class has the logic to validate a client, so the service use this class to authenticate the client.

In my case, the user and password are stored in a database, so I guess if I use the perCall instantiation of the service, the service would call to the database in each method call to validate the client, so I am thinking that it would be a bad idea for performing reasons. More considerating that the database has a hashed password, not the password, so I have to hash the password with the salt to compare the result with the hashed passowrd that I have stored. This would be very inneficient.

The behaviour is this, that the service would get the data from the database in each method call?

Another option would to have in memory all the users and password, but I don't know if this is a good idea, to have in memory all the passwords, for security reasons, and also because it could need a lot of memory only to store this information.

Another option it would be to use sessions, because I would have the session id and  then I could have in memory if a session logon or not. But if I am not wrong, sessions are used to ensure that the packages are send in order, so I shouldn't to use sessions for authentication purposes.

So in general, I would like to have some recomendation to implement authentication in a not reliable connection and without sessions.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, userName & password are validated when proxy is opened up so regardless of how many calls are performed, validation occures once unless you create new proxy for single invocation. Validation kicked off whenever invocation is sent could be brought in with custom *IDispatchMessageInspector* where you would check headers in order to retrieve username & password and validate them against database.

Comment: But if i do not use sessions, this is right too?  I mean if there is no session, the validation is done only once if i do not close the proxy?